Crashed: com.apple.network.connection EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000d25b5b890
i have strange crash on OS version: iPadOS 17.1.0 ,i can't reproduce.
Crashed: com.apple.network.connection-208
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3150 objc_retain_x23 + 16
1  Network                        0x64138 nw_connection_report_state_with_handler_on_nw_queue + 1548
2  Network                        0x20f64 __nw_connection_start_block_invoke + 428
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x26a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
5  libdispatch.dylib              0xb894 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748
6  libdispatch.dylib              0xc3f8 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 432
7  libdispatch.dylib              0xd6a8 _dispatch_workloop_invoke + 1756
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x17004 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x16878 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1964 _pthread_wqthread + 288
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8

    

